# Xamarin.Forms dropdown menus (ValidatablePicker) are not responsive in Android 9.0

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

It seems an issue that only affect Android devices running Android 9.0
A Xamarin.Forms app using MVVM pattern when deployed to an Android 9.0 device, the dropdown menus (`ValidatablePicker`s in a registration page) are not responsive and never expand.

The app runs OK on devices running iOS and Android earlier to 8.0

Is there a workaround to get the `ValidatablePicker`s to expand?

Comment: there is no XF control named "dropdown menu" so you need to be more specific about what you mean.  And it really helps to include the relevant code.

Comment: I've corrected that, thank you `ValidatablePicker`

Comment: that's a 3rd party plugin, not a core control.  I'd open an issue on their github page

Comment: Thanks again @Jason, is there an easy way (from within Visual Studio) to know if a control is a core control or a plugin?

Comment: not really, but if you look at the project page on Github it's obviously not owned by Microsoft/Xamarin